# Nothing happens when copying file with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose for a simple keycloak container and I've been trying to install a new theme for keycloak.
However I've been unable to copy even a single file to the container usnig a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are in the same directory

Neither of these commands work or cause any events or warnings in the logs.

```
COPY test /tmp/
COPY /home/adm/workspace/docker/keycloak-cluster/docker/kctheme/theme/login/. /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/keycloak/login/
```

Copying manually with

```
sudo docker cp test docker_keycloak_1:/tmp
```

works without any issues.

Comment: Did you re-run `docker build ` / `docker-compose build` ?

Comment: Tbh I never ran that command, only docker-compose up. (I just started to learn Docker) sudo docker-compose build
keycloak uses an image, skipping
Building mariadb
ERROR: No build stage in current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick understanding on Docker.

`docker build`: Create an image from a `Dockerfile`

`docker run`: Create a container from an image.

(you can create yourself the image or use a existing image from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com) )

Based on what you said, you have 2 options.

- Create a new docker image based on the existing one and add the theme.

something like

```
# Dockerfile
FROM jboss/keycloak

COPY test /tmp/
COPY /home/adm/workspace/docker/keycloak-cluster/docker/kctheme/theme/login/. /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/keycloak/login/
```

and then use `docker build` to create your new image

- Volume the theme in the correct directory

using docker-compose volume

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    volumes:
      - "./docker/kctheme/theme/login:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/keycloak/login"
```

Comment: Right I just read, that when using compose build and image are exclusive, which prohibited the use of the Dockerfile. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Files have to be in the same directory or a subdirectory of the directory with your Dockerfile build file if you use COPY, and have to be present at build time. No absolute paths.

/tmp as destination is also a bit tricky, because the startup process of the container might have a /tmp cleanout, which means that you would never see that file in a running container.